# Sources on bringing merit to the many

Tags: sources-mekorot, pirke-avot-ethicsof

It is written in Pirkei Avos that everyone who brings merit to the many(zichui ha rabim) no sin comes to his Hand. Can anyone plese give some more sources about the merit of those who bring merit to the many ( like distributing CD's or Books)to encourage ourselves to share more Torah wisdom with our fellow Jews.

Comment: Just take the founders of Mi Yodeya, they are all fabulously wealthy, famous, and saintly. Attractive too! :p

Comment: But seriously... I don't really understand the question you're trying to ask.